# What are some quick initial tests to check the quality of a new dataset?

Tags: dataset, quality-control, checking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Essential data checking tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11659/essential-data-checking-tests)

When you are presented with a dataset, what are some quick things you can look for to get a feel of how 'good' the dataset is. ('Good' in the sense of quality, reliability etc.). Any **generic** pointers?