# Things to consider about masters programs in statistics

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, careers

It is admission season for graduate schools. I (and many students like me) am now trying to decide which statistics program to pick.

1. What are some things those of you who work with statistics suggest we consider about masters programs in statistics?
2. Are there common pitfalls or mistakes students make (perhaps with regard to school reputation)?
3. For employment, should we look to focus on applied statistics or a mix of applied and theoretical statistics?

**Edit:** Here is some additional information about my personal situation: All of the programs I am now considering are in the United States. Some focus on the more applied side and give masters degrees in "applied statistics" while others have more theoretical coursework and grant degrees in "statistics". I'm personally not that intent on working in one industry over another. I have some programming background and know the tech industry a little better than, say, the genomics or bioinformatics industry. However, I'm primarily looking for a career with interesting problems.

**Edit**: Tried to make the question more generally applicable.

Comment: This depends very much on a lot of personal factors, making it hard to give good advice. We don't know what part of the world your programs are from, how focused your interests already are or what they are. The question is stated too broadly to be answered authoritatively, but would be at risk of being closed as *too localized* if it was geared solely toward giving advice to just one person. I suggest providing some more context, but not making it specific only to your particular case.

Comment: Fair enough. All the programs I am now considering are in the United States. Some focus on the more applied side and give masters degrees in "applied statistics" while others have more theoretical coursework and grant degrees in "statistics". 

I'm personally not that intent on working in one industry over another. I have some programming background and know the tech industry a little better than say the genomics or bioinformatics industry. However, I'm primarily looking for a career with interesting problems.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. I still think community wiki would be best, but this makes it possible for there to be a more productive conversation here. (deleting my previous comment.. )

Answer (score 47):

*Here is a somewhat blunt set of general thoughts and recommendations
on masters programs in statistics. I don't intend for them to be
polemic, though some of them may sound like that.*

*I am going to assume that you are interested in a terminal masters
degree to later go into industry and are **not** interested in
potentially pursuing a doctorate. Please do not take this reply as
authoritative, though.*

Below are several points of advice from my own experiences. I've
ordered them very roughly from what I think is most important to
least. As you choose a program, you might weigh each of them against
one another taking some of the points below into account.

1. **Try to make the best choice for you personally**. There are very
    many factors involved in such a decision: geography, personal
    relationships, job and networking opportunities, coursework,
    costs of education and living, etc. The most important thing is
    to weigh each of these yourself and try to use your own best
    judgment. **You** are the one that ultimately lives with the
    consequences of your choice, both positive and negative, and
    **you** are the only one in a position to appraise your whole
    situation. Act accordingly.
2. **Learn to collaborate and manage your time**. You may not believe
    me, but an employer will very likely care more about your
    personality, ability to collaborate with others and ability to
    work efficiently than they will care about your raw technical
    skills. Effective communication is crucial in statistics,
    especially when communicating with nonstatisticians. Knowing how
    to manage a complex project and make steady progress is very
    important. Take advantage of structured statistical-consulting opportunities, if they exist, at your chosen institution.
3. **Learn a cognate area**. The greatest weakness I see in many
    masters and PhD graduates in statistics, both in industry and
    in academia, is that they often have very little subject-matter
    knowledge. The upshot is that sometimes "standard" statistical
    analyses get used due to a lack of understanding of the underlying
    mechanisms of the problem they are trying to analyze. Developing
    some expertise in a cognate area can, therefore, be very
    enriching both statistically and professionally. But, the most
    important aspect of this is the learning itself: Realizing that
    incorporating subject matter knowledge can be *vital* to
    correctly analyzing a problem. Being competent in the vocabulary
    and basic knowledge can also aid greatly in communication and will
    improve the perception that your nonstatistician colleagues have
    of you.
4. **Learn to work with (big) data**. Data sets in virtually every
    field that uses statistics have been growing tremendously in size
    over the last 20 years. In an industrial setting, you will likely
    spend more time *manipulating* data than you will *analyzing*
    them. Learning good data-management procedures, sanity checking,
    etc. is crucial to valid analysis. The more efficient you become
    at it, the more time you'll spend doing the "fun" stuff. This
    is something that is very heavily underemphasized and
    underappreciated in academic programs. Luckily, there are now
    some bigger data sets available to the academic community that
    one can play with. If you can't do this within the program
    itself, spend some time doing so outside of it.
5. **Learn linear regression and the associated applied linear algebra
    very, very well**. It is surprising how many masters and PhD
    graduates obtain their degrees (from "top" programs!), but
    can't answer basic questions on linear regression or how it
    works. Having this material down cold will serve you incredibly
    well. It is important in its own right and is the gateway to
    many, many more advanced statistical and machine-learning
    techniques.
6. **If possible, do a masters report or thesis**. The masters
    programs associated with some of the top U.S. statistics departments
    (usually gauged more on their doctorate programs) seem to have
    moved away from incorporating a report or a thesis. The fact of
    the matter is that a purely course-based program usually deprives
    the student of developing any real depth of knowledge in a
    particular area. The area itself is not so important, in my view,
    but the experience is. The persistence, time-management,
    collaboration with faculty, etc. required to produce a masters
    report or thesis can pay off greatly when transitioning to
    industry. Even if a program doesn't advertise one, if you're
    otherwise interested in it, send an email to the admissions chair
    and ask about the possibility of a customized program that allows
    for it.
7. **Take the most challenging coursework you can manage**. While the
    most important thing is to understand the core material very,
    very well, you should also use your time and money wisely by
    challenging yourself as much as possible. The particular topic
    matter you choose to learn may appear to be fairly "useless",
    but getting some contact with the literature and challenging
    yourself to learn something new and difficult will make it easier
    when you have to do so later in industry. For example, learning
    some of the theory behind classical statistics turns out to be
    fairly useless in and of itself for the daily work of many
    industrial statisticians, but the concepts conveyed are
    *extremely* useful and provide continual guidance. It also will
    make all the other statistical methods you come into contact with
    seem less mysterious.
8. **A program's reputation only matters for your first job**. Way too
    much emphasis is put on a school's or program's reputation.
    Unfortunately, this is a time- and energy-saving heuristic for
    human-resource managers. Be aware that programs are judged much
    more by their research and doctoral programs than their masters
    ones. In many such top departments, the M.S. students often end up
    feeling a bit like second-class citizens since most of the
    resources are expended on the doctoral programs.

   One of the brightest young statistical
    collaborators I've worked with has a doctorate from a small
    foreign university you've probably never heard of. People can get
    a wonderful education (sometimes a much better one, especially at
    the undergraduate and masters level!)  at "no-name"
    institutions than at "top" programs. They're almost guaranteed
    to get more interaction with core faculty at the former.

   The name of the school at the top of your resume ***is*** likely to
    have a role in getting you in the door for your first job and
    people will care more about where your most advanced degree came
    from than where any others did. After that first job, people will care substantially more about what
    experience you bring to the table. Finding a school where lots of
    interesting job opportunities come to you through career fairs,
    circulated emails, etc., *can* have a big payoff and this happens
    more at top programs.

**A personal remark**: I personally have a preference for somewhat
  more theoretical programs that still allow some contact with data
  and a smattering of applied courses. The fact of the matter is that
  you're simply *not* going to become a good applied statistician by
  obtaining a masters degree. That comes only with (much more) time
  and experience in struggling with challenging problems and analyses
  on a daily basis.

Comment: +1.  Sometimes, as here, a good answer makes a question worth keeping.

Comment: I know this is a very individual decision. However, your thoughtful reply helps a lot. It is particularly interesting to see how highly you ranked learning a cognate area. Some programs allow me to take courses in other departments. I'm now starting to think that breadth is a particularly valuable characteristic of the program.

Comment: (+1) Very nice response. I particularly liked Point 3.

Comment: @AttemptedStudent: Traditionally, I think most graduate students (PhD, in particular) in statistics have undergraduate math backgrounds and have had little contact with actual applied problems that require statistical concepts and thinking. That may be part of the reason learning a cognate area ended up so high on my list. But, as I mentioned in the body, the ordering is a bit rough. :)

Comment: +1, nice answer. I liked points 3-5. Observation on data manipulation is spot on.

Comment: @AttemptedStudent: Here are a couple of questions that are broadly related to my answer that you might like to look through: [Essential data checking tests](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11659) and [Statistics education for a math PhD](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6538).

Comment: Thank you, all, for the very kind remarks. It's nice to see that some readers have found it useful. To be honest, at first, I was a little hesitant about posting it at all.

Comment: @cardinal Is it possible to start small, like earn a certificate (e.g., [here](http://math.kennesaw.edu/academics/certificate/appl-stat/index.html)) and afterward learn as you go while in the industry? Is that a realistic approach?

Comment: @Gues: I don't think you'd be likely to pick it up on the job. Which isn't to say there aren't plenty of people who through some combination of self-study, part-time or correspondence courses concurrently with work get to the same level (& by that time don't have to worry so much about Points 2 & 3). Also some basic statistics can still be another string to the bow of those who decide to go off in some other direction.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to either get in the best school possible with a brand name (like MIT), or the best overall deal (e.g. a decent public school with in-state tuition). I would not waste money on second rate private schools.

The brand name schools payoff. The price difference between a school like MIT and second tier schools like GWU is not big enough to justify the difference in the brand power.

On the other hand, some public schools, e.g. William and Mary, while being dirt cheap offer decent education. Some of them even have comparable brand power, e.g. Berkeley vs. Stanford. Thus due to the significant cost difference, they're an alternative to best private schools.

Answer (score -6):

Take a look at Pharmacoepidemiology. In particular as it relates to Drug safety. This is a very new area of research with a lots of very interested questions.

Comment: Was this accidentally posted in the wrong place?